# Dynamically change charts from a drop down with a changeable data range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I will be straight to the point, aassuming you got a set of some measured data, and there in a Column A you got a product name, in Column B number of tests you did (always different) and third Column C are the results.

I wanted to make a dynamic chart where everytime I change my product name (column A), I will be getting exactly the results and test numbers for a given product. Sometimes there will be 5 tests, sometimes 25, always differing, depending on a product.

My idea was dynamic named ranges for all the columns, and then connecting via drop downs. Maybe this job will be a bit tedious because of amount of data, or is there another way?

My data is looking exactly like this, so no TABLE format and with this "average" yellow row.

[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d42h2.gif)

Comment: you can create a pivot table/chart from the data set and have col A as the filter.

Comment: @PeterH Yes I kow, but in this exactly case I have to have it in a normal range, without Pivot Tables or Tables... (internal problem of the department) :=) any other option?

Comment: "internal problem of the department" - doesn't mean you should have to bend Excel to the will of the few. Pivot functionality exists for your use case. What can you do to address the "internal problem of the department"?

Comment: @spikey_richie  I dont need to explain details, if you can suggest me an option I would be grateful. 

Dont forget that lot of people doesnt know what Pivot tables are, dynamic ranges and so on =) So, I am keeping it simple as it can be.

Comment: @Mirza you could also create a sub-set of the data and chart from here, but this would be more complex than a pivot table. Pivot tables are as simple as it gets with Excel to be honest...

Comment: @PeterH You might be right. I will use Power Query + Pivot to assembly it as easy as it can be.